# Can i submit the same app icon for different apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use same icon for multiple ios (ipad/iphone) applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290690/can-we-use-same-icon-for-multiple-ios-ipad-iphone-applications)

I have one app in the international appstore and i want to submit the second only in hebrew and only for the israeli store.
can i use the same icon for both?

thanks!!!

Comment: Why don't/didn't you use the [internationalization and localization](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/) features the platform offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question asked over here : [Can we use same icon for multiple ios (ipad/iphone) applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290690/can-we-use-same-icon-for-multiple-ios-ipad-iphone-applications)

Answered by @sergio :

> There is no such rule, as far as I know. Indeed there are apps in the
>   App Store that have the same icon, and others with very minor
>   variations (e.g., the color tone).
>
> Apart from requirements about the size (of the different icon versions
>   you have to submit) that are relevant for approval, the only thing
>   that you should take into account (but this is not relevant for
>   approval) is that your app icon is attractive, reflect some how the
>   app functionality, and allows your app to be easily recognized.
>
> If your unique icon design satisfies this principle for you, then it
>   is fine.

If this answered your question, please also go over to that thread and upvote his answer.